# Using a for loop to count negative values and add to new column

Tags: r, for-loop, select, dataframe, negative-number

I'm pretty new to R and I want to experiment with different things in R.
I have created a dataframe and I want to use a for loop to select the number of negative values. I want to add this number to a new column in my dataframe. I know there are easier ways to do this, but I really want to get the hang of loops in R.
Does anyone of you have any advice for me? I'll post my data frame below.

newframe <- data.frame(V1=runif(500, min=-2, max=2),
                 V2=runif(500, min=-2, max=2))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are clearly easier way to do this, but I will give you some advice for a loop.
First, let's create an additional column :

```
nf=data.frame(newframe,neg=rep(NA))   #I called the column "neg"
```

Second, you have to define the range where the loop will start and end :

```
 for (i in 1:length(newframe[,1])) {

}
```

## comment : I wrote length(newframe[,1]) instead of 500 directly. It is always better to indicate something that is linked with the object you are using. For example, if you are adding more rows to your data.frame, it will be handled and your loop will still work.

Inside of the loop, if you only want the negative numbers you will have to use the IF condition to get them : 
(we are working here on the first column of your data frame but you could also do a "for" loop to work on every column)

```
 if(newframe[i,1]<=0){
  nf$neg[i]=newframe[i,1]
  }
```

Then you have your solution for the first column ! I let you do alone the second column :)

Answer (score 0):

First get the number of rows and columns of your dataset:

```
nr = NROW(newframe); # you can use the lowercase variant as well or the dim command
nc = NCOL(newframe);
```

and then cycle through rows and colums:

```
response = 0;
for(ir in 1:nr) { // cycle through rows

    for(ic in 1:nc) { // cycle through columns
        response = response + ifelse(newframe[ir, ic]<0, 1, 0);
    }

}
```

The `response` variable contains the number of negative values of your dataset.

The cycle works like a for-each statement, lets take into account the outer for-loop: `ir` will take all the values of the series generated by the command `1:nr` (that is `1`, `2`, ... `nr`).

Another example is

```
x = c("a", "b", "c");
for(v in x) { 
    cat(v, "\n"); 
}
```

you'll get the output

```
> a
b
c
```

This means you can achive the same result by using a single for-loop:

```
response = 0;
for(v in unlist(newframe)) { # you need to un-list the dataframe otherwise you would cycle through the columns...
    response = response + ifelse(v<0, 1, 0);
}
```

And you can always switch from a for-loop to a while loop if you prefer:

```
response = 0;
ir = 1;
while(ir<=nr) { // cycle through rows

    ic = 1;
    while(ic<=nc) { // cycle through columns
        response = response + ifelse(newframe[ir, ic]<0, 1, 0);
        ic = ic + 1;
    }
    ir = ir + 1;

}
```

I hope I have answered your question `:)`